# Memory Consumption and GC Performance Issues with HttpClient-5.2.1 in HTTP/2 Communication

Tags: https, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

After upgrading from version 5.1 to 5.2.1 of the HttpClient library for HTTP/2 communication, we encountered an issue. When connecting to any endpoint exposed by ALB (Application Load Balancer), our application consumes a significant amount of memory and fails to release it efficiently, leading to increased time spent on garbage collection (GC).

To illustrate the problem, I have provided a sample application that you can run. Even with only 100 requests, you will observe a rapid increase in memory usage. It's worth noting that the same code functions properly when using the HTTP/1.1 protocol.
The sample application has the following memory configuration: -Xms64m -Xmx512m.
Could you please help us identify the cause of this issue and suggest potential solutions?

Memory usage with http1.1:
[image]

Memory usage with http2:
[image]

```
`package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.async.methods.SimpleHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.async.methods.SimpleResponseConsumer;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.TlsConfig;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.HttpAsyncClients;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.hc.core5.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.nio.support.BasicRequestProducer;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http2.HttpVersionPolicy;
import org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOReactorConfig;
import org.apache.hc.core5.util.Timeout;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = provideHttpAsyncClient();
        client.start();
        ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(100);
        for(int i=0; i< 100; i++) {
            executors.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                  client.execute(new BasicRequestProducer("GET", new URI("https://www.figma.com/")),
                      SimpleResponseConsumer.create(),null, HttpClientContext.create(),
                      new FutureCallback<>() {
                        @Override
                        public void completed(SimpleHttpResponse result) {
                          System.out.println(result.getCode() + " " + result.getVersion());
                          countDownLatch.countDown();
                          System.out.println("Current heap size " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1000000 + "MB");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failed(Exception ex) {
                          System.out.println("Something went wrong... \n" + ex);
                          countDownLatch.countDown();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void cancelled() {
                          System.out.println("cancelled");
                          countDownLatch.countDown();
                        }
                      }
                  );
                } catch (InterruptedException | URISyntaxException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
        }
        countDownLatch.await();
        client.close();
        System.out.println("Client closed");
    }

    public static CloseableHttpAsyncClient provideHttpAsyncClient() {
        RequestConfig requestConfig = getRequestConfig();
        PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder connectionManagerBuilder =
            PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(100)
                .setMaxConnTotal(30)
                .setDefaultTlsConfig(prepareTLSConfig());

        PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager connManager = connectionManagerBuilder.build();

        IOReactorConfig ioReactorConfig =
            IOReactorConfig.custom()
                .setSoTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

      return HttpAsyncClients.custom()
          .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
          .setIOReactorConfig(ioReactorConfig)
          .setConnectionManager(connManager)
          .build();
    }

    static private TlsConfig prepareTLSConfig() {
        HttpVersionPolicy httpVersionPolicy =
            HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_1;
        return new TlsConfig.Builder().setVersionPolicy(httpVersionPolicy).build();
    }
    static RequestConfig getRequestConfig() {
        RequestConfig.Builder builder =
            RequestConfig.custom()
                .setResponseTimeout(
                    Timeout.ofSeconds(
                        15)) // Timeout until a new connection is fully
                // established
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(60))
                .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(60));
        return builder.build();
    }
}`
```

I have tried another library OkHTTP, it is working fine with that.

Comment: No one can help you just by looking at the screenshots. Create a test app or a Docker image that can be used to reproduce the issue and report it to the developers via JIRA ticket or at dev@hc.apache.org

Comment: Thanks, I have sent a email to dev@hc.apache.org with attached sample app, to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Your message went straight to the moderation queue. Why did not you subscribe?  Generally, stuff posted by non-subscribers gets ignored. https://hc.apache.org/mail.html

Comment: Thanks, sure I will subscribe now. I have debugged code today, I can see where it is taking more memory,  While making connection to an ALB end point(https://www.figma.com/) with http2, During handshake, on getting a setting frame, remote config max frame size is more than default one. And it is set as per the remote. (AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer.class in applyRemoteSettings method)
Local config max frame size - 65536
Remote config max frame size -  16777215 

Whereas with other endpoints I didn't see this.

Comment: I just ran your test app and reached the same conclusion. When using my local Apache HTTPD server your test app runs just fine with a stable memory footprint. If I run the test against figma.com the opposite endpoint negotiates protocol configuration with what appears to be a very high max frame size. I will try to investigate why that happens.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I observed the same behavior when run against google.com and figma.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens: both endpoints, the client and server, transmit their settings approximately at about the same time. The client states it can handle 64K frames at max, whereas the server states it can handle 16MB frames. The client ACKs the server settings because its MAX_FRAME_SIZE is lesser than that of the server. The server, however, just ACKs the client settings without re-sending its settings with a smaller MAX_FRAME_SIZE. I suppose what means is the server acknowledges the client settings including the limit and states its intent to respect it and the client can be reasonably sure it will never get hit with a frame greater than 64K, but I have to got to revisit the HTTP/2 specification to be sure.

Therefore, assuming my understanding of the specification proves correct this looks like a defect in HttpClient.

Please raise a JIRA for this defect
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HTTPCORE/

```
ex-0000000001 preparing request execution
ex-0000000001 target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
ex-0000000001 proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
ex-0000000001 acquiring connection with route {s}->https://www.figma.com:443
ex-0000000001 acquiring endpoint (3 MINUTES)
ex-0000000001 endpoint lease request (3 MINUTES) [route: {s}->https://www.figma.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 25]
ex-0000000001 endpoint leased [route: {s}->https://www.figma.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 25]
ex-0000000001 acquired ep-0000000001
ex-0000000001 acquired endpoint ep-0000000001
ep-0000000001 connecting endpoint (null)
ep-0000000001 connecting endpoint to https://www.figma.com:443 (3 MINUTES)
www.figma.com resolving remote address
www.figma.com resolved to [www.figma.com/18.165.183.28, www.figma.com/18.165.183.33, www.figma.com/18.165.183.31, www.figma.com/18.165.183.109]
www.figma.com:443 connecting null->www.figma.com/18.165.183.28:443 (3 MINUTES)
www.figma.com:443 connected null->www.figma.com/18.165.183.28:443 as c-0000000000
c-0000000000 start TLS
Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Starting handshake (3 MINUTES)
Secure session established
 negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
 negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
 peer principal: CN=*.figma.com
 peer alternative names: [*.figma.com, figma.com]
 issuer principal: CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02, O=Amazon, C=US
ep-0000000001 connected c-0000000000
ep-0000000001 endpoint connected
ex-0000000001 connected to target
ex-0000000001 route fully established
ex-0000000001 executing GET / HTTP/1.1
ep-0000000001 start execution ex-0000000001
ep-0000000001 executing exchange ex-0000000001 over c-0000000000
c-0000000000 RequestExecutionCommand with NORMAL priority
c-0000000000 >> stream 0 frame: SETTINGS (0x4); flags: (0x0); length: 36
c-0000000000 >> HEADER_TABLE_SIZE: 8192
c-0000000000 >> ENABLE_PUSH: 1
c-0000000000 >> MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS: 250
c-0000000000 >> INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE: 65535
c-0000000000 >> MAX_FRAME_SIZE: 65536
c-0000000000 >> MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE: 16777215
c-0000000000 << stream 0 flow control 2147418112 -> 2147483647
c-0000000000 << stream 0 flow control 2147483647 -> 2147483647
c-0000000000 >> stream 0 flow control 65535 -> 65535
c-0000000000 << stream 0 frame: SETTINGS (0x4); flags: (0x0); length: 18
c-0000000000 << MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS: 128
c-0000000000 << INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE: 65536
c-0000000000 << MAX_FRAME_SIZE: 16777215
c-0000000000 << stream 0 frame: WINDOW_UPDATE (0x8); flags: (0x0); length: 4
c-0000000000 << Increment 2147418112
c-0000000000 >> stream 0 flow control 2147418112 -> 2147483647
c-0000000000 << stream 1 flow control 65535 -> 65535
c-0000000000 >> stream 1 flow control 65536 -> 65536
ex-0000000001 Cookie spec selected: strict
ex-0000000001 send request GET / HTTP/1.1, null entity
c-0000000000 >> :method: GET
c-0000000000 >> :scheme: https
c-0000000000 >> :authority: www.figma.com:443
c-0000000000 >> :path: /
c-0000000000 >> user-agent: Apache-HttpAsyncClient/5.2.2-SNAPSHOT (Java/1.8.0_342)
c-0000000000 >> stream 0 frame: WINDOW_UPDATE (0x8); flags: (0x0); length: 4
c-0000000000 >> Increment 2147418112
c-0000000000 >> stream 0 frame: SETTINGS (0x4); flags: ACK (0x1); length: 0
c-0000000000 << stream 0 frame: SETTINGS (0x4); flags: ACK (0x1); length: 0
```

Comment: Thanks, raised below Jira,
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-751

Comment: We just ran into this issue and are now testing the fixed version

Comment: Meant to also append the following to the previous comment:

However, looking at the code change I wonder: if the receiving server indicates it can receive with a frame size larger than FrameConsts.MIN_FRAME_SIZE, the current code will never send those larger frames (unless you reconfigure the local H2Config), correct?

As you don't want to create a large buffer up front (as it might never get used, thus useless allocation), should the buffer not auto-resize to a larger size (up to the indicated remote maxFramePayloadSize) when trying to send frame content that doesn't fit?